# Data from database show/hide onclick trouble

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
$getNews = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
$getNews->execute();
$news = $getNews->fetchAll();
foreach ($news as $newspost) {
    echo $newspost['title'] ; ?> <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="return    toggleMe('problem')">read/hide</a>
<?php
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Posted by '; echo $newspost["user"]; echo ' at '; echo $newspost["created"];  ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $newspost['id']; ?>" style="display:none;"> 
<?php
    echo $newspost['message'];
?>
    </div>
<?php
    echo '<br /> <br />';
}
?>
```

What I had in mind was that it shows/hides the text from the newspost when you hit the read/hide link next to the title of the newspost.
I can fit the `$newspost['id']` in the representing div but because the `onclick="return toggleMe('problem')">` has both `"` and `'` in it I need another way to fit it in there, I searched a lot but couldn't find what I was exactly looking for.

Comment: look for `escaping quotes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you'll be fine with:

```
"return toggleMe('<?php echo $newspost['id']; ?>');"
```

The inner single quotes will never be seen in the output HTML, and the `<?php ?>` block doesn't care what quotes surround it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, i was thinking way to far out of the box it seems, thanks again!